# R: monte carlo integration using Importance Sampling

Tags: r, statistics, pdf-generation, probability

I have an integral to evaluate

```
      "x^(-0.5)" ; x in [0.01,1]
```

for which I am using Importance Sampling MC :
The theory says that an approximate PDF has to be used to compute the expected value (which will almost surely converge to the mean - value of the integral)

After plotting the given integral, and exponential PDF, based only on the plots, I chose the
 `rexp` and `dexp` to generate the PDF - and my code looks like this -

```
#Without Importance Sampling
set.seed(1909)
X <- runif(1000,0.01,1)
Y <- X^(-0.5)
c( mean(Y), var(Y) )

#Importance sampling Monte Carlo
w <- function(x) dunif(x, 0.01, 1)/dexp(x,rate=1.5)
f <- function(x) x^(-0.5)
X= rexp(1000,rate=1.5)
Y=w(X)*f(X)
c( mean(Y), var(Y) )
```

---

Could someone please confirm if my line of thought is correct?
If wrong, how differently am I supposed to approach this? 
Please elucidate - I have understood the theory but implementation is proving to be problematic for me.

For integrals that are not so simple,

1.) **f(x)** = [1+sinh(2x)ln(x)]^-1 
I chose the **normal PDF = g(x)** (with mean = 0.5 and SD = 5) as approximate only after observing the plot. I wrote a code similar to the one for it , but it says NaN's produced in case of importance sampling. (this ideally means undefined function but I don't know how to solve this).

2.) **f(x,y)** = exp(-x^4 - y^4)

How do I choose the **g(x,y)** for the above function ?

Answer (score 4):

Generally your approach seems to be correct, but you have to be more careful with the domain over which you want to integrate. In your original example, about 20% of values `rexp(1000, 1.5)` are above 1. The function `dexp(x, rate=1.5)` is not a density function on the interval [0,1]. You have to divide by `pexp(1, rate=1.5)`. So here is what I would do for the importance sampling example:

```
#Importance sampling Monte Carlo
w <- function(x) dunif(x, 0.01, 1)/dexp(x,rate=1.5) * pexp(1, rate=1.5)
f <- function(x) x^(-0.5)
X <- rexp(1000,rate=1.5)
X <- X[X<=1]
Y <- w(X)*f(X)
c(mean(Y), var(Y))
```

In your second example the same thing causes the problem. You get negative X and therefore get NA values for log(X). Furthermore, your normal function should be centered at 0.5 with less variance. Here's my approach:

```
#Without Importance Sampling
set.seed(1909)
X <- runif(1000,0.01,1)
Y <- (1+sinh(2*X)*log(X))^(-1)
c(mean(Y), var(Y))

#Importance sampling Monte Carlo
w <- function(x) dunif(x, 0.01, 1)/dnorm(x, mean=0.5, sd=0.25) * (1-2*pnorm(0, mean=0.5, sd=0.25))
f <- function(x) (1+sinh(2*x)*log(x))^(-1)
X <- rnorm(1000, mean=0.5, sd=0.25)
Y1 <- w(X)
Y2 <- f(X)
Y <- Y1*Y2
Y <- Y[!(is.na(Y2)&Y1==0)]
c(mean(Y), var(Y))
```

In your second example, I don't really understand what `y` is. Is it just a constant? Then perhaps a Weibull distribution may work.

EDIT: Regarding your additional questions in the comments. 
(1) Any probability density function should integrate to 1. Therefore `dexp(x, rate=1.5)` is not a density function on the interval [0,1], it only integrates to `pexp(1, rate=1.5)`. However, the function

```
dexp01 <- function(x, rate){
  dexp(x, rate=rate)/pexp(1, rate=rate)
}
```

actually integrates to 1:

```
integrate(dexp, 0, 1, rate=1.5)
integrate(dexp01, 0, 1, rate=1.5)
```

That's the rationale of including the probability distribution function. If you have a different interval, e.g. [0.3,8], you have to adjust the function accordingly:

```
dexp0.3_8 <- function(x, rate){
  dexp(x, rate=rate)/(pexp(8, rate=rate)-pexp(0.3, rate=rate))
}
integrate(dexp0.3_8, 0.3, 8, rate=1.5)
```

(2) Here I choose the variance so that approximately 95% of the values in `rnorm(1000, .5, .25)` were in the interval from 0 to 1 (having many values outside this interval would certainly increase the variance). However, I am not certain that this is the best choice of distribution function. The selection of the importance function is a problem that I am not very familiar with. You could ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Same goes for your next question.

Comment: first of all, thank you for a positive and detailed explanation.

More questions:
1) `pexp` is the PDF, got it. But what is the motivation or the basis of choosing to include it? If my interval were between x in [0.3,8] , would it matter?

2) I made a mistake in mentioning the mean, it was indeed 0.5 that I took. However, how does one decide on less variance? I'm thinking I might've understood the concept wrong- the PDF chosen should more or less cover the integral to be evaluated correct? or does it have to follow the curves& peaks, and give more importance to the bulk of the peak?

Comment: Also, the second example is a double integral.
If I have more than one variable - like `x^2 + y^2` --x,y in[-1,1] or `exp^(x+y)` or the above function.

How do I choose the PDF's for these? and given that we don't have standard functions to generate samples from these in R, do I have to generate samples from another method? perhaps, Accept-Reject?


(I realize it's very long questions but I'd be ever so grateful for explanations  that will cement the concept in my head)