# R - Importance Sampling to solve Integrals

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I have referred to these links - 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060675/r-monte-carlo-integration-using-importance-sampling) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060675/r-monte-carlo-integration-using-importance-sampling). The latter link is a question of mine, but the answers, as they turn out, aren't quite right.

Hence I am creating asking a question with new attempts made to answer it.

- I have the following integral

  ```
             (x^-0.5)                                   ;in x=[0.01,1]
  ```

  To solve this using Importance Sampling MC integration, one needs to select an **importance pdf** that is approximately the same as the **function plot**

My R code to solve the same is this :

```
#function 1 - importance sampling
w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.01,1)/dbeta(x,0.7,1)
f <- function(x) x^(-0.5)
X <- rbeta(1000,0.7,1)
Y <- w(X)*f(X)
c(mean(Y),var(Y))
```

**True integral value** - 1.8

**Using the Importance Sampling code above** - 1.82 (where my importance PDF is ***Beta(0.7,1)***

which is quite alright so I'm assuming the code is correct.

- Now I have this integral

  `[1+sinh(2x)ln(x)]^-1                                     ;in x=[0.8,3]`

for which my code is :

```
#function 2 
w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.01,1)/dnorm(x,0.5,0.25)
f <- function(x) (1+sinh(2*x)*log(x))^(-1)
X <- rnorm(1000,0.5,0.25)
Y <- w(X)*f(X)
Y <- Y[!is.na(Y)]
c(mean(Y),var(Y))
```

**True Integral Value**  ~0.601

**Value from executing above code** ~3.25 (where my importance PDF is ***normal(0.5,sd=0.25)***

---

What am I doing wrong?

1) Take function to be evaluated as f(x).

2) Generate samples from Importance PDF g(x) that is truncated between the intervals.

3) Get the mean(f(x)/g(x)) which is the integral.

---

**EDITS**

According to Nishanth's suggests, made the changes in the code like so:

```
 set.seed(19)
 w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.8,3)/dnorm(x,0.8,1.49)
 f <- function(x) (1+sinh(2*x)*log(x))^(-1)
 X <- rnorm(1000,0.8,1.49)
 X <- X[X > 0.8 & X < 3]
 Y <- w(X)*f(X)
 c(mean(Y),var(Y))
```

However, even though the estimate is close to the real value, the variance reduction isn't happening (compared to brute force MC and stratified sampling)

Also, uploading the plot of the function to be integrated if anyone wants to verify the choice of importance PDF.
[image]

Comment: are you sure the true integral value is 0.7? [I tried wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bsinh%282x%29ln%28x%29%29+from+0.3+to+8) and got 2.8

Comment: Positive . Used integrate function in R as well.

Comment: Okay "ln" in R is log(x). Made a mistake there. The answer is about ~0.601. 

Made the changes along with log(x) and the ones you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of weight function plays a vital role in Importance Sampling. To get faster convergence, parameters have to be tuned - which is mostly ad-hoc when proper inverse function does not exist. I would make the following changes to your code:

```
> w <- function(x) dunif(x,0.3,8)/dnorm(x,0.3,0.4)
> f <- function(x) (1+sinh(2*x)*log(x))^(-1)
> X <- rnorm(1000,0.3,0.4)
> X <- X[X > 0.3 & X < 8]
> Y <- w(X)*f(X)
> c(mean(Y),var(Y))
[1] 0.703766099 0.005848816
```

Comment: Hello,
apologies for the wrong information (which explains the wrong integral value). The interval is [0.8,3] and not [0.3,8] 

But it still works. 

That brings me to my question - if you were to approach a problem, you would first plot the importance PDF and observe I suppose (if it's close to the given PDF or not.)

But post that, how does one go about accurately choosing it? Are there any pointers you could give?


Thanks!

Comment: for `[0.8,3]` you need to change the `mean` in both `dnorm` and `rnorm` to 0.8 too. Then it works. So that is one pointer - choosing proper mean. Also your function `f` resembles an exponential curve, so you can choose `dexp/rexp`

Comment: Please have a look at the edits. Also, no the function f doesn't resemble exponential at all.
looks somewhat like a normal. I have added the plot.

Hence the choice behind normal importance PDF. Also, please do check your mail. Much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to execute this in any other way rather than what's implemented ?